# Neo4j APOC custom function hangs when nothing is found

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have written the following custom function that performs a complex search and returns a list of IDs. Here is a simplified version:

```
CALL apoc.custom.declareFunction('test()::LIST OF INTEGER?', '
    MATCH (m:Movie)
    WITH m.id AS id
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN id
')
```

The function is intended to be used in the following query:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE m.id IN custom.test()
RETURN m.title AS title
```

When testing the function with `RETURN custom.test() as ids`, the execution result is `[{'ids': [57]}]`

In the case where the function finds nothing (for the simplified version, I replace `LIMIT 1` with `LIMIT 0`), I expect the function to return `[{'ids': []}]`. However, instead, **it simply hangs**.

I have tried defining the return type as both `LIST OF INTEGER` and `LIST OF INTEGER?`.

Is this an APOC bug? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Limit 0 means return ALL so it hangs now. Do UNWIND test() rather than usng IN clause

Comment: @jose_bacoy No, `LIMIT 0` means return nothing (from the `WITH` clause, in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although adding `OPTIONAL` to the `MATCH` statement indeed helped to avoid hanging, this approach is only applicable to `MATCH`, not to `CALL`.

I propose a general solution:
At the end of the query, we should collect all the results into an array using `COLLECT()` and create the function with the parameter `forceSingle = true`:

```
CALL apoc.custom.declareFunction('test(limit :: INTEGER)::LIST OF INTEGER?', '
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m.id AS id
LIMIT $limit
RETURN COLLECT(id)
', true)
```

Now, calling the function `RETURN custom.test(0) as ids` returns `[{'ids': []}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your custom function's query to this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Movie)
RETURN m.id AS id
```

If there are no `Movie` nodes, the `OPTIONAL MATCH` will cause `[NULL]` to be returned from your custom function, and your test query will work as expected (i.e., return no results) in that case.

You can test that the custom function works when there are no results by replacing `:Movie` with `:FooBar` in its query (instead of using `LIMIT 0`).

Comment: Thank you for your help with the correct answer! This solution works perfectly and resolves the issue. However, there are a couple of misunderstandings remaining. Why does Neo4j still hang without the OPTIONAL clause? Is it a bug in Neo4j (perhaps in APOC)? And is there a way to return [] instead of [NULL] (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: I don't know of a way to just return `[]`. Hanging should never happen, so you should create an [extended APOC issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
UNWIND custom.test() as id
MATCH (m: Movie) where m.id = id
RETURN m.title AS title
```

UNWIND is like a for loop so it will fix your code and will not hang.
Please test it out.

Comment: {code: Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed} {message: Cannot invoke "org.neo4j.values.AnyValue.estimatedHeapUsage()" because "value" is null}